# zend framework2 Shibboleth Adapter - How to setup a adapter

Tags: zend-framework2, shibboleth

I am a new user of Zend framework2 can you please suggest me on how to authenticate my users with Shibboleth.

Comment: Such an adapter currently does not exist. Check [existing Adapters](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/tree/master/library/Zend/Authentication/Adapter) and write your own Shibboleth Adapter and share it with the community :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have an existing Shibboleth authentication package, you can wrap it in a class that implements Zend\Authentication\Adapter\AdapterInterface.

Comment: I want to use this package [ivan-novakov / zf-shib-auth], please tell me how to wrap it in class in zend2, thanks

Comment: You might want to take that particular library and give it some refactoring. That lib has dependencies to Zend 1.X interfaces. You wouldn't want to mix 1.X and 2.X (not that you couldn't, just kind of dirty)

Comment: That same developer has a shibboleth adapter for zend 2 available [link]https://github.com/ivan-novakov/zf2-shibboleth-authentication